# Processes are randomly killed

Tags: macos, mac, xcode, ventura, ruby

Ever since I've upgraded to Ventura the processes are randomly terminating with Killed 9 signal.

For example:

I am trying to install a new version of ruby using `rbenv install 3.2.2` and am seeing killed 9 signal being sen (see below)

```
opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@11/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include -MMD -MF crypto/seed/libcrypto-shlib-seed_cbc.d.tmp -MT crypto/seed/libcrypto-shlib-seed_cbc.o -c -o crypto/seed/libcrypto-shlib-seed_cbc.o crypto/seed/seed_cbc.c
make[1]: *** [crypto/seed/libcrypto-shlib-seed.o] Killed: 9
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
clang: error: unable to execute command: Killed: 9
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
make[1]: *** [crypto/seed/libcrypto-shlib-seed_cbc.o] Killed: 9
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/sh/01k8dfc529q8srsbj35rnbr40000gp/T/rsa_x931-fd450d.c
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/sh/01k8dfc529q8srsbj35rnbr40000gp/T/rsa_x931-fd450d.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /Users/zlatansadibasic/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash
clang: note: diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************
make[1]: *** [crypto/rsa/libcrypto-shlib-rsa_x931.o] Error 254
make: *** [build_sw] Error 2
```

However this is not specific to using rbenv command or installing ruby. Every so often I get killed 9 signal being sent to some of the git commands when they are run in iterm2 as well.

Comment: Did you migrate from an Intel Mac to a Silicon Mac?

Comment: No, I was on M1 the whole time.

Comment: There seems to be a build error with the `libcrypto-shlib-rsa_x931.o`. This might not be related to macOS at all.  Have you checked with whatever package you’re trying to install to see if this issue exists?

Comment: The kernel seems to be sending kill 9 signal. I run the same command repeatedly, and it does not fail at the same place.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: the ball was in your court to watch/investigate the library in question.  What have you found?

Comment: But it isn't just the library. It stops at different stages during the compilation phase. I ran command 5 times and the process gets killed at different spot

Comment: Those would be key in helping the diagnosis.  This is like going to the doctor with swollen ankles, numbness in the extremities, trouble breathing, and tiredness while resting but only mentioning the ankles.  The issue here would be a failing heart but we don’t know that because we only focused on one thing.

Comment: I do not think so. It started happening once I've upgraded to Ventura. I could be executing any shell command, and it will randomly get killed. 
Even simple:
git pull
ls -all

would result in the process being killed before it had a chance to execute. This all started happening after an upgrade to Ventura.